# In the debugger what is the difference between: Raised Exceptions, Uncaught Exceptions and User Uncaught Exceptions?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So in the bottom left of VSCode when you debug there's this menu:
[image]

I'm trying to understand what the difference is between "Raised Exceptions", "Uncaught Exceptions" and "User Uncaught Exceptions." It seems when I have "Raised Exceptions" and "User Uncaught Exceptions" the code will actually stop itself on some exceptions that it can normally ignore and still execute when they are off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Raised Exceptions**: This is more of a manual exception raised by user to check for certain condition, and if that condition is true, then a warning is thrown.
- **Uncaught Exceptions**: These are Exceptions that arise outside the scope of "Throw/Catch" Exception handling that the user creates.
- **User Uncaught Exceptions**: These are Exceptions from user creation with "Throw/Catch" methodology.

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code Debug Mode, In general:

- **Raised Exceptions**: pauses when any exception is thrown, whether it's *caught or not.
- **Uncaught Exceptions**: pauses when an exception is thrown and not *caught  in the code.
- **User Uncaught Exceptions**: *uncaught exceptions originate from user code, not libraries.

*An 'exception' is exemplified by Python's Try/Except structure.
P.S. The behavior may vary slightly with different programming languages.